# Kotlin Enum with String Room TypeConverter

Tags: kotlin, enums, android-room, data-class

I'm fetching json that has a 'type' field that contains a string, and I want to store this in my model object as an Enum with a string value.

The API I'm working with doesn't return all the information in one fetch, so once I have all the data I call my setProperties method.

All of my primitives are stored correctly in memory & my room db, but my Type class isn't converted. Any idea whats wrong with my type converter?

```
// Enum
enum class Type(var value: String) {
    ARTICLE("article"),
    COMMENT("comment"),
    UNKNOWN("unknown")
}

// data class
data class FeedItem(@PrimaryKey override var id: Int) : Item(id) {

    @TypeConverters(TypeConverter::class)
    var type: Type? = Type.UNKNOWN

    // other props...

    fun setProperties(itemToCopy: FeedItem) {
        this.type = itemToCopy.type
        // set other props
    }

}

// TypeConverter
class TypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(type: Type?): String? {
        return type?.value
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toType(value: String?): Type? {
        return when(value) {
            Type.ARTICLE.value ->Type.ARTICLE
            Type.COMMENT.value -> Type.COMMENT
            else -> Type.UNKNOWN
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: > but my Type class isn't converted
Could you elaborate on that? Do you get any error message during compilation or at runtime?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear of me. The type class isn't stored in my room db, when i inspect my sqlite.db with stetho all the other properties are there. There is no compilation or runtime error, the 'type' property is null even though my typeconverter has a fallback to return a type.unknown if not matched to the json response

Comment: Ok, if there's no error you could actually debug the insert down to the sql code that is generated (the java code is generated by or is part of room library). 
If you see the column as `null` in the database itself and there was no error I'm pretty sure this entity was saved without the `type` column value.